# How to use count in Query builder Laravel5.6

Tags: laravel, count

This is my query builder. But an error is shown

> ERROR => count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements
>   Countable

```
Route::get('project', function () {
        $project = DB::table('pams_project')
         ->join('pams_developer', 'pams_project.dev_id', '=', 'pams_developer.id')
         ->select(array('pams_developer.developer_name',DB::raw(count('pams_project'.'dev_id'))))
        ->get();
        return view('projectByDeveloper', ['project' => $project]);
    });
```

can anyone figure out my problems ?

Comment: try this `DB::raw("count('pams_project'.'dev_id') as count")`;

Comment: @webinion thx for reply, i try your suggestion but it show Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'as' (T_AS), expecting ',' or ')'

Comment: updated my comment

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But i follow your suggestion but it show SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1140 In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'sam-21.pams_developer.developer_name'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select pams_developer.developer_name, count(pams_project.dev_id) as count from pams_project inner join pams_developer on pams_project.dev_id = pams_developer.id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `DB::raw("count(pams_project.dev_id) as count")`

```
$project = DB::table('pams_project')
         ->join('pams_developer', 'pams_project.dev_id', '=', 'pams_developer.id')
         ->select(array('pams_developer.developer_name',DB::raw("count(pams_project.dev_id) as count")))
        ->get();
```

But also make sure to use `GroupBy()` with this.

If you want to get the count of collection u can simply use `$project->count()`

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But i follow your suggestion but it show  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1140 In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'sam-21.pams_developer.developer_name'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select `pams_developer`.`developer_name`, count(pams_project.dev_id) as count from `pams_project` inner join `pams_developer` on `pams_project`.`dev_id` = `pams_developer`.`id`)

Comment: Ohh, I solved after I use GroupBy. Thanks you so much.

Comment: @WeiKang you can turn off this error by setting `strict mode to false`

Comment: levaral, how to turn off ? just link change the sql mode in phpmyadmin ?

Comment: in config/database.php  find the strict => true, set it to false

Comment: levaral, okay, thansk for your advice